# What is the asymptotic complexity of?

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

$$T(n) = \begin{cases}T\left (n/\log_2{n}\right) + 1 & n>2\\1&n\leq 2\end{cases}$$

I'm tempted to think that the answer is $\Theta(\log n)$, but the denominator decreases as $n$ decreases. Some computer aided trials suggest that $T(n)$ grows slower than $\log_k n$ for any constant $k$

Comment: Hint: What if $n$ is $2^{2^k}$ for some $k \in\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: Intuition: If you were dividing by a constant $a,$ i.e. $T(n) = T(n/a)+1,$ it would be of order $\Theta(\log n).$ But in fact your division can get larger and larger!